# FineUploader.js how to conditionally rescale and compress images?

Tags: image-uploading, fine-uploader

This [part of the documentation](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/scaling.html#only-upload-scaled-files) is relevant to what I want to do, but it looks hard-coded:

```
var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
    ...
    scaling: {
        sizes: [
            {name: "small", maxSize: 100},
            {name: "medium", maxSize: 300}
        ]
    }
});
```

I would like the rescaling to be done conditionally to images that aren't already compressed by the user.

Here is some pseudocode of what I want to accomplish:

```
if ((filesize < 1 megabytes) and (image.width*image.height > 1 megapixels)) {
  Keep the original image without manipulating it in any way
} else {
  Rescale image longest side to maximum of 1600 pixels
  Compress the image to 60% quality
  if (filesize still > 1mb) {
    Keep compressing with more jpeg until it's under 800kb
  }
}
```

I don't know if fine-uploader has the jpeg compression functioniality in-built (or if it's only rescaling), if it doesn't then perhaps [J-I-C](https://github.com/brunobar79/J-I-C) could be used.

If this conditional rescaling and compression can be accomplished with fine-uploader, how should it be done? If not, what other paths should I consider?

Comment: Also, please see this in-progress feature, which will be part of Fine Uploader 5.10.1. It will allow you to delegate to an image resize library of your choice. https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/1525

Comment: Thanks! Is this feature something that only fine-uploader is implementing, or have other libraries such as jquery-file-upload implemented it as well?

Comment: No idea, but none of the other upload libraries are actively developed or well maintained anymore. I doubt the few that do offer scaling offer this sort of flexibility.

Comment: If you are interested in testing the feature I referenced above before it is released (so that you can provide feedback and influence any changes), you will want to comment in the GitHub issue.

Comment: Ah I just realized you're the lead developer for fine-uploader! It's an honor haha :) I will definitely look into it, thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to "conditionally" scale images, you will need to implement this logic yourself using the [`scaleImage` API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#scaleImage).

1. Construct a Fine Uploader instance. Do not include [`scaling` options](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html#scaling).
2. Contribute an [`onSubmitted` callback handler](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#submitted). There, you can check the file using the [`getFile` API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#getFile), and use this to determine if the file should be scaled.
3. If the file should be scaled, create a scaled `Blob` using `scaleImage`, and then submit the scaled `Blob` to Fine Uploader via the [`addFiles` API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#addFiles).